# Compiling and installing dante server from source for Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apt, compiling, proxy

The apt repositories for dante server for Ubuntu 16.04 are outdated (version 1.1).
So I need to compile the program from source and install it because I don't want to use an untrusted PPA.

Usually when I install from repositories, `apt install dante-server` and it's installed! and if you do `danted -v` it prints the version, and you can edit your dante config file in `/etc/danted.conf` and restart the `danted` service and use your proxy server! But when I compile and install the program, it's still not usable the way I described.

---

Here's what I've done so far:

I downloaded the dante-1.4.2.tar.gz from their website https://www.inet.no/dante/download.html and did:

```
./configure
make
make check
sudo make install
```

But when I try `danted -v` I see it's not installed yet (also checked under `/usr/bin` and `/usr/sbin` and `/etc/init.d`). So from the `INSTALL` readme file inside the downloaded tar.gz file, I found out the program gets installed in `/usr/local`.

```
$ ls /usr/local/bin
socksify
$ ls /usr/local/sbin
sockd
```

But as you can see it's not installed, only socksify and sockd are installed. I believe sockd is a dependecy of dante-server.

Also, I found no service named danted in systemctl, how do I install the service?

`configure` status:

```
                 Configure status:

Client:            Enabled
Server:            Enabled
Preloading:        Enabled
Libwrap:           Disabled, tcpd.h missing
BSD Auth:          Disabled, usable bsd_auth.h not found
PAM:               Disabled, security/pam_appl.h missing
GSSAPI:            Not found/disabled
KRB5:              Not found/disabled
SASL:              Not found/disabled
UPNP:              Not found/disabled
Compatability:     issetugid setproctitle strlcpy strvis

                     Modules:

redirect:          Not found
bandwidth:         Not found
ldap:              Not found
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that the binary has been correctly installed - it's called `sockd`. This is the default name for this binary. You can rename it with `mv /usr/local/sbin/sockd /usr/local/sbin/danted` You can configure this, along with the default config file with configure options such as `--with-sockd-conf=FILE` It's the same with the apache2 binary in Ubuntu. In RHEL/Fedora, this binary is called `httpd`.

Since you have edited your question several times, some of this may no longer appear relevant:

When you manually compile/install, the default install location for binaries is `/usr/local/bin`. Check that this is in you PATH var with `echo $PATH`.

`libscompat/timer.h` is a C header file.

`/usr/local/man/man5/socks.conf` is not a config file, it's a `man` page.

Read the contents of this file with `man /usr/local/man/man5/socks.conf` and you will get an idea of what to put in `/etc/socks.conf`

You would normally be able to enable this with `systemctl enable dante.service`, but you will need to manually create the systemd service file in `/usr/lib/systemd/system/`

Here's an example of danted.service from 20.04:

```
[Unit]
Description=SOCKS (v4 and v5) proxy daemon (danted)
Documentation=man:danted(8) man:danted.conf(5)
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
PIDFile=/run/danted.pid
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/danted
ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c ' \
    uid=`sed -n -e "s/[[:space:]]//g" -e "s/#.*//" -e "/^user\\.privileged/{s/[^:]*://p;q;}" /etc/danted.conf`; \
    if [ -n "$uid" ]; then \
        touch /var/run/danted.pid; \
        chown $uid /var/run/danted.pid; \
    fi \
    '
PrivateTmp=yes
InaccessibleDirectories=/boot /home /media /mnt /opt /root
ReadOnlyDirectories=/bin /etc /lib -/lib64 /sbin /usr /var
DeviceAllow=/dev/null rw

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: But my question is how to compile and install this. I've read the man pages and readme files and doc folder, I tried other dante versions all the way down to 1.1.19, I can't compile and install any of them. Also, I don't have `system` dir in `/usr/lib/systemd/`

Comment: As I've said, `sockd` is a dependency, `danted` which is the proxy server, is not getting installed. My question is I need instructions on how to successfully compile and install the program. The "what I've done so far" part is just for letting readers know how much of it I've accomplished and where my problem lies. Have you successfully compiled and installed the program from source? If not or you don't know how to do that then why are you writing this answer? Thanks for your time. I appreciate it.

Comment: What do you mean by 'dependency'? `sockd` is not a dependency, it's the binary. This is the default name for this binary. You can rename it with `mv /usr/local/sbin/sockd /usr/local/sbin/danted`
You can configure this, along with the default config file with configure options such as `--with-sockd-conf=FILE`
It's the same with the `apache2` binary in ubuntu. In RHEL and Fedora, this binary is called `httpd`.

Comment: $ sockd -v Makes sense! Now I'm just one step away from getting it to work, is it ok if I just copy paste the service file? I think it's platform dependant.

Comment: How about upvoting the answer, since it has answered your question? The systemd service file is a separate question and there is heap of info about that on this platform, coupled with the example I gave, it should be pretty easy to sort figure out.

Comment: I did before! Thank you. Do you happen to know if I can use the program without a service? Is the daemon mode for this purpose? `sockd -D` is daemon mode. Also, it would be great if you included the information you gave me on your first comment above in your answer, because comments might get purged by moderators.

Answer (score 1):

When you install dante server from source/tarball file, it installs binary as `sockd` in `/usr/bin`. You can rename `sockd` binary to `dante`, if you wish. If you do so, you need to also update name in service file.

You can configure dante server in `/etc/sockd.conf`.
Example configuration is below.

```
internal: eth0 port = 3000
external: INSERT-YOUR-EXTERNAL-IP
socksmethod: none
logoutput: syslog stdout /var/log/sockd.log
client pass {
  from: 0.0.0.0/0 port 1-65535 to: 0.0.0.0/0
  clientmethod: none
  log: connect error
}
socks pass {
  from: 0.0.0.0/0 port 1-65535 to: 0.0.0.0/0
  clientmethod: none
  log: connect error
}
```

When you install dante server by compiling from source, 
Sockd service is not created but You can create sockd service manually.

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/sockd.service
```

Copy below content to editor, save and close it.

```
[Unit]
Description=Sockd Service
[Service]
Type=normal
ExecStart=/usr/local/sbin/sockd
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

You would be able to start sockd service and enable it at boot.

```
sudo systemctl start sockd
sudo systemctl enable sockd
```

Comment: I'm getting error on `rpmbuild -ba dante.spec` : `error: Failed build dependencies:
  bison is needed by dante-1.4.2-1.x86_64
  flex is needed by dante-1.4.2-1.x86_64
pam-devel is needed by dante-1.4.2-1.x86_64` I tried `sudo apt install bison flex libpam0g-dev` but it didn't fix the problem.

Comment: Is it ok if I just ignore the dependencies with `--nodeps`? I tried `yum` and `yum-utils` to fix the dependencies but it doesn't work on Ubuntu.

Comment: You need  bison flex glibc-devel libtool pam-devel libraries to build rpm packages. Don't ignore dependencies.

Comment: These two `glibc-devel` `pam-devel` are not available on Ubuntu 16.04 unfortunately.

Comment: Build essentials will install glibc-devel in ubuntu and libpam0g-dev will install pam-devel libraries. See in answer step of installing dependencies.

Comment: I even had these installed `autoconf automake binutils` but still getting the error on first comment. I checked this tutorial too https://vulners.com/avleonov/AVLEONOV:78040042688AB39AEFD5B6B594A4B7A3 it uses the sockd service at the end idk how!! Also I couldn't find anything about service file not getting installed in the spec file.

Comment: yes, you are right, rpmbuild can't detect those binaries.

Comment: In that case, you can drop idea of building rpms and try to  configure from installation you already done.